Trackpad settings seem not to affect anything in 24.04
The GUI trackpad settings for my Lenovo 16IAX7 running ubuntu 24.04 6.8.0-48-generic  don't seem to affect the scrolling behavior. (Neither do the mouse settings). I am using the Gnome DE and Mutter WM. I've gone through the post here but this doesn't seem to be entirely relevant to my case as (for instance) I don't see a natural scroll option. How would I get the GUI to work, or  get natural scrolling running some other way?

xinput --list gives a list of input devices of which #14 is my trackpad. So
xinput --list-props 14 gives the list of properties one of which is the "Synaptics Scrolling Distance" (no Natural Scrolling appears).
Synaptics Scrolling Distance (358): -86, -86

By setting the scrolling distance to negative instead of positive values I get natural scrolling:
xinput --set-prop "14" "Synaptics Scrolling Distance" -86 -86.
